# Plot of (magnetic susceptibility times temperature) versus temperature

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism

I have a part in my chemistry course, where I have to read about the magnetic properties of bulk materials i.e. paramagnetism, ferromagnetism and antiferromagnetism. Now in the lectures, I was told about the Curie and the Curie-Weiss law for paramagnets. I was also shown the magnetic susceptibility($\chi$) vs temperature ($T$) graphs that look like this:

[image: chi vs T for para, ferro and antiferro-magnetic materials]

(Image from [this](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Inorganic_Chemistry_(Housecroft)/20%3A_d-Block_Metal_Chemistry_-_Coordination_Complexes/20.10%3A_Magnetic_Properties/20.10C%3A_The_Effects_of_Temperature_on_Magnetic_Moment) page)

Now in the exams, one of the questions asked me to draw the plot of $\chi_m T$ vs $T$. I assumed that $\chi_m$ meant the molar susceptibility. The Curie law ($\chi = 1/T$) means that, for paramagnetic materials, the plot of $\chi_m T$ would be a straight line vs T, I can draw that.

**How can I draw the $\chi_m T$ vs $T$ plot for the other materials (ferro- and antiferromagnet)?** My guess is that, for antiferromagnets, the plot will go down sharply at the Neel temperature. I don't know what would happen for ferromagnets.

I have googled this, but most graphs seem to be $\chi$ vs $T$, and I can't find what I need. Any references to books or articles where $\chi T$ vs $T$ plots are shown are also welcome.